# Display error each field with twig

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, twig

I have a problem with displaying errors with twig.

The errors are displayed in the last form_error with twig and I do not know how to fix it to display each error in his field.
I use annotation for constraints in my entity like  * @Assert\True(message = "This field is empty")

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}


<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register" novalidate="novalidate">

{{ form_errors(form) }}
<article class="form-part part1">
    <h2>1 - Information pour la création du compte</h2>
    <label for="{{ form.pays.vars.id }}">Pays <span>*</span> : </label>
    {{ form_widget(form.pays) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.pays) }}

    <label for="{{ form.username.vars.id }}">Pseudo <span>*</span> : </label>
    {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.username) }}

    <label for="{{ form.email.vars.id }}">Email <span>*</span> : </label>
    {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}

    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword) }}

    <div class="birthday">
        {{ form_row(form.birthday) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_row(form.nationalite) }}
</article>
<article class="form-part">
    <h2>2 - Télécharger les 6 images de votre galerie</h2>
    <div>
        {{ form_row(form.images, {'label': ' '}) }}
    </div>
</article>

<div class="bottom-form">
    <div class="contrat-cgu">
        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.certificatAge) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.certificatAge) }} 
            {{ form_errors(form.certificatAge) }}
            <a href="{{ path('cgv_read')}}" target="_blank">Lire les Conditions générales d'utilisation</a>
        </div>


        <div>
            {{ form_label(form.artistContract) }} 
            {{ form_widget(form.artistContract) }}  
            {{ form_errors(form.artistContract) }}
            <a href="{{ path('contratArtiste_read')}}" target="_blank">Lire le Contrat artiste</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form_row(form.how) }}

    {{ form_rest(form) }}

</div>
```

If someone has an idea